# iferror & iserror vba runtime error 1004 in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

Does Excel allows iferror and/or iserror as part of a Range(X, Y).Formula = definition?

I have tried with iserror and iferror, but I always get a runtime error 1004

```
.Range(ActiveCell, "AJ" & lastRow).Formula = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(RIGHT([@[ga:sourceMedium]],LEN([@[ga:sourceMedium]])-FIND(""/"",[@[ga:sourceMedium]],1))),'Objetivos y Configuración'!R2C5:R19C6,2,0),""No definido"")"
```

I don't see anything wrong in that code :s

Comment: Your structured refernce (`[@[ga:sourceMedium]]`) doesn't look right and may be the cause of your error.  Can you describe what you are trying to reference?

Comment: @chrisneilsen. I am referencing a column in a table (not a list). That is a good point. Maybe if I substitute those references with RC[X] will help!

Comment: With RC[X] works! Thanks!